# Running an NSRunLoop with different dates changes observed thread count

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsthread, nsrunloop

While writing an app, I encountered some odd behavior that I wasn't expecting and distilled it down to the following:

I made an app whose main function is as follows. While observing it in Activity Monitor, it uses one thread.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        while (YES)
        {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode
                                     beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If I change `[NSDate distantFuture]` to `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0]`, the app uses ~3 threads. After inspecting this a bit it appears that a `dispatch_queue` has been implicitly created on my behalf which in turn makes a thread pool.

Just curious: why does this happen? What about `[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1.0]` causes the run loop to create a `dispatch_queue`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, an implementation detail and nothing to worry about....

One possibly implementation of `distantFuture` is "do it forever" and, therefore, no need for a timer like the one w/a specific date.  Given that "timer" might actually be `dispatch_after()`, that might explain the queue.

Or not.   Interesting question, but likely quite thoroughly irrelevant to your app.

Comment: I concur with Bill, it's an implementation detail along the lines of "how many retains are on my object" that should be considered only as a most irrelevant curiosity. That said, I do think that it's likely that distantFuture means "run forever until an input source fires" while giving it a specific time requires that it create a timer source, on some level, to drive the automatic interruption of the run loop.

Comment: I had assumed it was nothing to worry about but I was still very curious anyway. I always like to know more about stuff like this. Thanks to both of you!